# setTimeout works in my looping javascript slideshow functions for a while, then ceases to delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, settimeout

[My slideshow](http://ccchico.com/NewSite/) has gone through several iterations, but it has never shaken off this issue. It will run for a while as expected, then suddenly begin switching slides without any delay. If it weren't for the animation it'd probably run at light-speed...

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/> 
        <meta name="Description" content="Calvary Chapel Chico is a non-denominational,Bible-believing church established to worship,glorify,and share the good news of our Lord and Savior,Jesus Christ." /> 
        <title>Calvary Chapel Chico</title>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:regular,bold"/>-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Top450">
            <div id="TitleBar">
                <div id="Logo"></div>
                <h1>Calvary Chapel Chico</h1>
                <a id="Login" href="">Login</a>
            </div>
            <div id="SlideShow">
                <div id="Banner">
                    <div id="SMedia">Insert Media Links Here</div>
                    <div id="SMinistries">Insert Ministry links Here</div>
                    <div id="SServiceTimes">Insert Service Times Here</br><div style="background:#fff;">TEST</div></div>
                    <div id="SWelcome">Welcome to</br><span id="WelcomeText">Calvary Chapel Chico Online</span></div>
                    <a id="S5" href="2.html">2</a>
                    <a id="S6" href="2.html">3</a>
                    <a id="S7" href="2.html">4</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="MenuBar">
                <div class="Pages">
                    <a id="Home" href="2.html" class="current">Home</a>
                    <a id="About" href="2.html">About</a>
                    <a id="Media" href="#" rel="1" class="SlidePage">Media</a>
                    <a id="Ministries" href="#" rel="2" class="SlidePage">Ministries</a>
                    <a id="ServiceTimes" href="#" rel="3" class="SlidePage">Service Times & Directions</a>
                </div>
                <div class="BannerButtons">
                    <a href="#" rel="4"></a>
                    <a href="#" rel="5"></a>
                    <a href="#" rel="6"></a>
                    <a href="#" rel="7"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Body">
            <div id="Left300">
                <div id="LeftTopTabs" class="Tabs">
                    <div id="LeftTopTabBar" class="TabBar">
                        <a href="#LTT-1">News</a>
                        <a href="#LTT-2">Media</a>
                        <a href="#LTT-3">Calendar</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="LeftTopPanes" class="Panes">
                        <div id="LTT-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                        <div id="LTT-2">Nunc in tempor sem.</div>
                        <div id="LTT-3">Sed diam nisl,</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Right700">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Bottom450">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
$(
    function() {

//===================================================================================================================================
//Setup
//===================================================================================================================================

//Initialize variables
        var Pause
        var NextSlide
        var RepeatTimer
        var SlideshowTimer
        var $CurrentSlide

//Slideshow setup
        $(".BannerButtons a:first").addClass("current");//Force the first slide's button to be the "CurrentSlide"
        $(".BannerButtons").show();
        var SlideWidth=$("#SlideShow").width();
        $("#Banner").css({'width':[SlideWidth*[$("#Banner>*").size()]]});

//Tabs setup
        var $CurrentTab=$(".TabBar a:first").next();

//===================================================================================================================================
//Slideshow Functions
//===================================================================================================================================

//Move to the Next Slide
        NextSlide=function(){
            var image_reelPosition=[$CurrentSlide.attr("rel")-1]*SlideWidth;//Computes distance to the left edge of the slide in pixels
            $(".BannerButtons a,.SlidePage").removeClass("current");//Make the old "CurrentSlide" no longer the "CurrentSlide"
            $("#Banner").animate({left:-image_reelPosition},900);//Next slide animation
            $CurrentSlide.addClass("current");//Make the new "CurrentSlide" current
        };

//Repeat slide changes
        RepeatTimer=function(){
            $CurrentSlide=$('.BannerButtons a.current').next();//Make the next "CurrentSlide" current
            if($CurrentSlide.length===0){$CurrentSlide=$('.BannerButtons a:first');};//If end of buttons is reached, go back to the beginning
            NextSlide();//Go to the next slide
            SlideshowTimer();
        };

//Repeat slide changes every 10 seconds
        SlideshowTimer=function(){
            clearTimeout(Pause);//Clear the timer
            Pause=setTimeout(RepeatTimer,10000);//Reset the timer
        };

//Hover
        $("#Banner").hover(
            function(){//Hover trigger
                clearTimeout(Pause);//Clear the timer
            },function(){//Cease to hover trigger
                Pause=setTimeout(RepeatTimer,2000);//Reset the timer
        });

//Click
        $(".BannerButtons a,.SlidePage").click(
            function(){
                $CurrentSlide=$(this);//Make the clicked object the "CurrentSlide"
                clearTimeout(Pause);//Clear the timer
                NextSlide();//Go to the clicked slide
                SlideshowTimer();//Reset the timer
                return false;//Keep the # out of the URL
            }
        );

//===================================================================================================================================
//Tab Functions
//===================================================================================================================================

//Move to the clicked tab
        ChangeTab=function(){
            $(".TabBar>a").removeClass("current");
            $CurrentTab.addClass("current");//Force the first slide's button to be the "CurrentTab"
            $CurrentPane=$($CurrentTab.attr("href"));
            $(".Panes>div").addClass("HiddenPane");
            $CurrentPane.removeClass("HiddenPane");
        };

//Click
        $(".TabBar>a").click(
            function(){
                $CurrentTab=$(this);//Make the clicked object the "CurrentSlide"
                ChangeTab();//Go to the clicked tab
                return false;//Keep the # out of the URL
            }
        );

//===================================================================================================================================

//Start Slide Show
        SlideshowTimer();

//Initialize Tabs
        ChangeTab();

//END
    }
);
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why it would speed up and stay sped up, but in your `.hover()` handler you're clearing and resetting the timer to 2000 (two seconds), while your main `SlideshowTimer` function uses 10000 (ten seconds). I'd suggest you define a constant to hold the delay time, and/or restart the timer by calling `SlideshowTimer` from within the `.hover()` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! Turns out it was a Browser/Javascript issue. I didn't realize just how jQuery queues up all the animations by default.

So, first off, page loaded, everything was fine. No timing issues. Then I go to another tab and leave my page open. That's where this is stemming from. The browser somehow is locking jQuery out of animating the animations (not immediately though) with CSS changes when it wants to. But at the same time the Javascript timer does continue. All the while jQuery is building a queue of un-performed animations. When you reopen the tab the browser let's jQuery have its way and begins running all the queued animation back-to-back. At which point the timer script is still running, but it only gets to add changes to the queue. And so it appears that the timer has failed.

**THE FIX**

I changed:

```
$("#Banner").animate({left:-image_reelPosition},900);//Next slide animation
```

to:

```
$("#Banner").stop().animate({left:-image_reelPosition},900);//Next slide animation
```

And that's it, jQuery knows that building a queue is not desirable for some animations, so it includes a fix.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see is that you're calling `clearTimeout(Pause)` a lot without knowing whether `Pause` is a valid and active timerID.  In many cases, you're calling it with an old timerID that has long since finished (and thus is no longer valid).  The OS may tolerate that, but then again it could cause some issues.

Usually, the solution to this is to set the timerID variable to null whenever your timer fires or you clear the timer and then check for null before calling clearTimeout.

Also, as nnnnnn said in their comment, putting the mouse over the slideshow will drop the timer time from 10 seconds to 2 seconds.  If you had a 2 second animation, that would be nearly the entire time.

I'd recommend making a function for setting the slide timer and a function for clearing the slide timer and then you can centralize the management of both the timer ID and the time that the timer is set for.

My guess is that the core problem is the 2 second issue on hover, but you should clean up your timerID management too.